# Charles-proxy iPhone Connection

Tags: ios, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm trying to sniff my iPhone with charles-proxy but charles proxy is not detecting my iPhone.

My computer is connected in ethernet, and with my computer i did an hotspot to have wifi on my iPhone.

Here the step i followed:

**On my computer**:

1.Installed charles proxy

2.Go to help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles Root Certificate on a Mobile Device or Remote Browser

3.Copied the IP and the PORT

**On my iPhone**:

1.Go to Settings App -> WIFI

2.Click on the "i" near the connected wifi

3.Changed the PROXY HTTP to manual and pasted the IP and PORT from charles proxy

But charles proxy is not detecting my iPhone and i have no access to internet with my iPhone when i'm "connected" to the proxy;

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Note that on iOS 10 and later you must then go into Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings and enable the Charles certificate to be trusted.

Comment: Yes i know this but the problem is that i can’t install the certificate because the proxy is not working on my iPhone because it’s not detected by Charles.

Comment: maybe your Mac use outside VPN?

Comment: It’s a PC and not i’m not using a VPN, it seem like the problem is that my iPhone is connected to the hotspot that my PC is sharing but the PC is connect with ethernet directly, because when my PC and my iPhone are connected to the same WIFI it’s working, but in this case it’s not and i don’t know why.

Comment: Any news on this? I've run into exactly this as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the [Charles App](https://apps.apple.com/app/charles-proxy/id1134218562), is an option to sniff directly from mobile. But if you want to use on Desktop, you need to [install the certificate](http://www.charlesproxy.com/getssl/) on iPhone before.

Answer (score -1):

check you iphone any vpn connected  close it first